# Is there a better way to determine the most trusted users in a bookstore database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm building a web portal for a bookstore.

I want to allow users to mark other users as "trusted" or "not-trusted".

I want to figure out who are our stores most trusted users by ordering on their overall trust level.

Here's an example to illustrate how this trust level is calculated:

We are going to calculate Bob's trust level...

Bob has been marked as "trusted" by 100 other users, and marked as "not trusted" by 20 users. Bob's trust level = 100 - 20 = 80.

I have the following table:

Judges(judgerLoginName: VARCHAR(45), judgedLoginName VARCHAR(45), trustLevel SMALLINT)

Now, currently I have a trustLevel of 0 representing "not-trusted" and 1 representing "trusted".

So, I'm thinking about changing all the 0's to -1's, so I could do a simple:

```
SELECT judgedLoginName, SUM(trustLevel)
FROM Judges
GROUP BY judgedLoginName,
ORDER BY SUM(trustLevel) DESC
```

However, I would like to know if there was an equally simple means to subtract countOfNotTrusted from countOfTrusted. What do you suggest? I'm quite new to database development and would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: A bit of a newbie myself, but what you're suggesting sounds fine to me

Comment: You might leave a threshold of say 3 votes __having count(*) > 3; __ and display *unknown* if there are no rows in result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT judgedLoginName, SUM(IF(trustLevel = 0, -1, 1))
FROM Judges
GROUP BY judgedLoginName,
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

- Check if your trust level is 0, then the value that is added is -1
- Added the order by 2 to order by the second column if you need to

Comment: `ORDER BY 2` sorts by column name 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT judgedLoginName, -COUNT(*)+2*SUM(trustLevel)
FROM Judges
GROUP BY judgedLoginName,
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

gives all users a value of `-1` and adds the trusted ones `+2`, resulting in `+1` for them.